# Is it possible to simplify $n \equiv - \frac d 4\bigg(\frac 3 2\bigg)^{m-2} - 2 \pmod {3^m}$ further?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, integers

Is it possible to simplify this further:

$$
n \equiv - \frac d 4\bigg(\frac 3 2\bigg)^{m-2} - 2 \pmod {3^m} \qquad \text{where } n, d \geq 0 \text{ and } m \geq 2 \text{ are integers}
$$

or to glean some info on what $n$ should be to satisfy the equivalence?

---

I obtained the above as follows:

I want to know when

$$
\frac 1 {3^m} \big(2^m(n+2) - (2 - \Delta) 3^m \big)
\qquad
\text{where } \Delta = \frac d 9 \text{ for some integer } d \geq 0
$$

is an integer. We have

$$
\begin{align}
2^m (n+2) &\equiv (2 - \Delta) 3^m &\pmod {3^m}\\
2^m (n+2) &\equiv (2 - \frac d 9) 3^m &\pmod {3^m}\\
2^m (n+2) &\equiv 2 \cdot 3^m - \frac d {3^2} \cdot 3^m &\pmod {3^m}\\
2^m (n+2) &\equiv - d \cdot 3^{m-2} &\pmod {3^m}\\
4 \cdot 2^{m-2} (n+2) &\equiv - d \cdot 3^{m-2} &\pmod {3^m}\\
n+2 &\equiv - \frac d 4 \bigg(\frac 3 2\bigg)^{m-2} &\pmod {3^m}\\
n &\equiv - \frac d 4 \bigg(\frac 3 2\bigg)^{m-2} - 2 &\pmod {3^m}
\end{align}
$$

From $2^m (n+2) \equiv - d \cdot 3^{m-2} \pmod {3^m}$, I know that if $d \equiv 0 \pmod 9$, then $n \equiv -2 \pmod {3^m}$.

Also, by writing $d = 9k + (d \bmod 9)$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
2^m (n+2) &\equiv - (9k + (d \bmod 9)) \cdot 3^{m-2} &\pmod {3^m}\\
2^m (n+2) &\equiv -9k \cdot 3^{m-2} + -(d \bmod 9) \cdot 3^{m-2} &\pmod {3^m}\\
2^m (n+2) &\equiv -k \cdot 3^m + -(d \bmod 9) \cdot 3^{m-2} &\pmod {3^m}\\
&\boxed{
2^m (n+2) \equiv -(d \bmod 9) \cdot 3^{m-2} \pmod {3^m}
}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Simplfy $n \equiv - \dfrac d 4\bigg(\dfrac 3 2\bigg)^{m-2} - 2 \pmod {3^m} \qquad \text{where } n, d \geq 0 \text{ and } m \geq 2 \text{ are integers}$.

Multiplying by $\dfrac94$ we get
$$\dfrac94n\equiv -\dfrac d4 \left(\dfrac 32\right)^m-\dfrac 92\pmod{3^m}\Rightarrow 9n\equiv \left(\dfrac{-d}{2^m}\right)3^m-18\pmod{3^m}$$ Then $$\boxed{n\equiv-2\mod{3^m}}$$

Comment: Thanks! Don't I we need $d \equiv 0 \pmod {2^m}$ to make that final simplification?

Comment: @joseville: Non. because $d3^m$ is a multiple of $3^m$ (not necessary to multiply by $\dfrac 94$, just by $9$ and you get the same result).

Comment: Thanks, I may not understanding, but what if $\frac d {2^m}$ is not a whole number?